# Process Monitor: exclude all selected events

Tags: windows, process-monitor

Alternative question:
Windows (Sysinternals) Process Monitor (**PM**): How to add to active filter all currently selected events at once?

A very common scenario of using PM is an attempt to catch specific activity (i.e. specific registry or file access) related to some user action (**UA**).
Usually it means finding a needle in a list of 100-1000 logged events.

One way to reduce the amount of events is to start a capture and then activate the UA very fast.

Another way is to use the program a bit without the specific UA, then to manually exclude common logged events, and then (while log activity is reduced because most of the common events are being filtered out) triggering the UA.
Manually excluding every event type in this approach requires way too much user input (adding 10-100-... filters).

<sub>It's also possible to use PM without the UA, save log, use again with UA and then subtract the unique log entries, but this will often require much more time than manual adding to exclude and this is not interactive enough in many cases.</sub>

Is there a way to exclude all selected events simultaneously?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here: The log is never "practically empty". PM always logs all the events, filtered or not. The filters only change what is *shown*. If the log file is very large, filtering and display will be slow. There exist in the Filter menu the commands "Save filter" and "Load filter", and filter rules can be set to Exclude. So where is the problem?

Comment: @harrymc about misunderstanding - in the question it was mentioned "because all possible unrelated events are being filtered out", deleted not implied. The problem is not too large and slow log or PM interface, but way too much manual input required. Selecting multiple events is already supported - so it looks like excluding multiple at once could be supported too. Clarified question slightly.

Comment: It seems to me that you can save the group of filters once with Include and once with Exclude. You may "Load filter" one and/or the other over the same log.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @harrymc question is not about bulk save load at all, pinpointing the UA is supposed to be done over single execution of program and then PM. Question is just about real-time bulk exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appeared to be much more trivial than expected, bulk exclude can be done via
**Right click -> Exclude -> Path**.

Wish this menu entry was labeled "Exclude all" if multiple entries are selected, since other actions on top of the same menu don't support bulk.

Also in very, very rare cases this won't be enough since the idea was to bulk exclude exact matches (same Process name, same Operation, same Path), not only same Path as in this answer.